# Dot product zero but np.corrcoef returns a negative value

Tags: python, numpy, correlation, numpy-ndarray

can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong here (image of the code attached)? When I do the dot product, I get almost 0 value but np.corrcoef returns a significant negative correlation value.

```
eigenvectors_sorted[0:2]
> array([[-0.4252893 ,  0.42100611,  0.71434339,  0.36276216],
       [ 0.14612219,  0.90470509, -0.33510219, -0.21877734]])

np.corrcoef(eigenvectors_sorted[0], eigenvectors_sorted[1])
> array([[ 1.        , -0.16304091],
       [-0.16304091,  1.        ]])

np.dot(eigenvectors_sorted[0], eigenvectors_sorted[1])

> 5.551115123125783e-17
```

I am expecting np.corrcoef to also return 0 value and not -0.163, I am unable to understand what am I doing wrong.

Comment: See [Pearson correlation coefficient: for a sample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#For_a_sample) for the correlation coefficient formula.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not mesuring the same thing, (better ask on [stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com) for a mathematical explanation).

Quick demonstration that the correlation is independent of the number of points, while the dot product is not, by repeating the data many times with `np.repeat`:

```
eigenvectors_sorted = np.repeat(eigenvectors_sorted, 100, axis=1)

np.corrcoef(eigenvectors_sorted[0], eigenvectors_sorted[1])
# array([[ 1.        , -0.16304092],
#        [-0.16304092,  1.        ]])

np.dot(eigenvectors_sorted[0], eigenvectors_sorted[1])
# -8.079945611472183e-07
```

With an even greater number of points:

```
eigenvectors_sorted = np.repeat(eigenvectors_sorted, 1_000_000, axis=1)

np.corrcoef(eigenvectors_sorted[0], eigenvectors_sorted[1])
# array([[ 1.        , -0.16304092],
#        [-0.16304092,  1.        ]])

np.dot(eigenvectors_sorted[0], eigenvectors_sorted[1])
# -0.008079939827439375
```